# The hyperlink <a> not responsive with post?

Tags: responsive

I'm using semplicemente theme .(http://crestaproject.com/demo/semplicemente/).

But in my post which have a hyperlink look like

```
<a href="link">conent</a>
```

And when i test it's responsive, everthing working great except the hyperlink.

I tried to reinstall the fresh install theme. But it still error.

Any idea?

Comment: [Responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) is a term widely used now for design pattern. Your question seems obscure to us. Please [edit] your question and rewrite with the correct information in other wordings. And please note, third party products are off-topic here. We request you to contact the author or their dedicated support forum for the support.

Comment: I just want to research why the <a> tag isn't responsive. Thank for your comment.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about `<a>` tag to be responsive. If you mean it dosen't break link content, then use CSS property `word-wrap`. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Comment: I'm guessing by "not responsive" you actually  mean nothing happens when you click it. For us to have any chance of helping with that, we'd need to look at the actual page (could be, for example, a syntax error somewhere else in your HTML, a problem with the formatting of the actual link or some javascript elsewhere on your page that is disabling the link.)

Comment: It mean the text content with hyperlink it doesn't fit to the frame, it keep a long line and not warp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the element once in "responsive mode" and check if no CSS is missing.

You could also post a screenshot for us to see what you mean by 'not responsive'.

Comment: It mean the text content with hyperlink it doesn't fit to the frame, it keep a long line and not warp.

Comment: Like @Rene said, try to use `word-wrap: break-word;`. If it's not working, inspect the HTML to see if a parent is taken more width than it should.